# How can I fix Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk's failing tests?

Tags: perl, mechanicalturk

I'm using Perl 5.10.0 on Debian Linux (testing) and trying to install the Perl module [Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Amazon-MechanicalTurk) version 1.01. When I run the module's test suite, I get errors such as the following:

```
t/01-ListOperations.......................Can't locate object method "new" via package "Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk::Transport::RESTTransport" at /home/user/.cpan/build/Net-Amazon-MechanicalTurk-1.01-BO885C/blib/lib/Net/Amazon/MechanicalTurk/Transport.pm line 21. 
dubious 
[...] 
Failed 21/33 test scripts. 12/78 subtests failed. 
Files=33, Tests=78, 46 wallclock secs ( 1.50 cusr +  0.22 csys =  1.72 CPU) 
Failed 21/33 test programs. 12/78 subtests failed.
```

`Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk::Transport::RESTTransport` ISA `Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk::Transport` which ISA `Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk::BaseObject` which has a sub "new".

I have all of the required modules installed, as verified by the `mturk_install.pl` script. I've checked the issues on the module's CPAN page, but these errors are not addressed.

Has anyone had these problems and come up with any solutions? If you're successfully using this module, which version of Perl are you running?

Answer (score 4):

The CPAN Testers had a similar experience.

http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.cpan.testers/2009/03/msg3437850.html

Answer (score 2):

You should submit a bug report to [CPAN bugtracker's queue for Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk](http://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Queue=Net-Amazon-MechanicalTurk)

Answer (score 2):

I've build a small patch that helps solve this problem.  There's an error in the internal logic of the library which prevented all the modules from loading properly.  Check out the patch and my description at http://daveviner.blogspot.com/2009/12/amazon-mechanical-turk-perl-library.html

Answer (score 1):

I've applied Dave Viner's patch and two of the patches in the RT queue. There's an unauthorized release with version 1.01_01 in [my CPAN directory](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/). I'll check the CPAN Testers response for the fixes and work on an official release after that. If you're the original author, please contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post, but even in new 1.02 version it is still an issue. It is easy to fix tho - just remove "defined" from line 35 of lib/Net/Amazon/MechanicalTurk/ModuleUtil.pm and you are done. Apparently everybody at Amazon run old version of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

According to CPAN Testers, the latest version of Perl which worked with [Net::Amazon::MechanicalTurk](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Amazon-MechanicalTurk) was 5.8.9. I built a local copy for use with this specific module.